# No package nginx-plus-module-brotli available error - Amazon Linux 2 LTS

Tags: nginx, brotli

I want to install Brotli following [the documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/dynamic-modules/brotli/), on Amazon Linux 2 LTS.

```
yum install nginx-plus-module-brotli
```

But I am getting:

```
No package nginx-plus-module-brotli available.
```

Does this mean that the documentation is outdated (package has a new name?)... or is there something I am missing?

How can I debug this situation?

Thanks.